# Blender video editing cut but use original encoding

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I want use Blender to cut out some scenes from a video and save in original encoding format. Cut only no rendering, no encoding. What I have to do ?

Comment: Suggest using ffmpeg from command line, or a tool like [avidemux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux)

Comment: Unless the codec is MPEG2, you can't indiscriminately chop codecs together.